# Difference between throughput and total amount of data

Tags: throughput

I believe this is NOT a throughput vs bandwith question.

I am reading docs for an API and it says the following:

> Each shard has 2MB throughput, and  returns up to 10MB of data

Does this mean my api call will take 5 seconds if it needs to collect 10MB of data? How does the api call return a max of 10MB of data when the throughput is 2MB?

Comment: That documentation makes no sense. Throughput is a per-time measure. (Or per instruction, or per clock cycle, you get the idea.) MB, being a unit of data amount, cannot be a unit of throughput.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I believe they were saying 2MB/s throughput then

Comment: But then you answer your own question, through speculation. Don't think you'll get any further than that.